# Не работает функция распознавания, если вводить цифры, а потом вставить между ними букву

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция для распознавания цифр, она работает, если вводить буквы или если вводить цифры, а потом буквы, но если вводить цифры, а потом вставить между ними буковку, не работает и видит её как цифру

```
function Check(e) {
    var val = e.value;
    var pattern = /[0-9]/;
    for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var res = pattern.test(val[i]);
    }
    if (res == true) {
        e.nextSibling.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        e.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'Введена не цифра';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Check(e) { 
    var val = e.value; 
    var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/;

    var res = pattern.test(val);

    if(res) {
        console.log('ok');
    } else{
        console.log('err');
    } 
}
```

м?

Comment: `[0-9]` разве не `\d`?

Comment: @Spectre можно и так. Можно и так: [:digit:]

Answer (score 3):

```
function Check(e)
{
    if(e.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    {
        alert('Цифры');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Косяк');
    }
}
Check('111');
Check('1a1');
```

Comment: а почему match? test раза в 2-3 быстрее же.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/test-vs-match/2 синий и оранжевый показатели

Comment: @Palmervan ну так и у какой же функции всё-таки больше операций в секунду?)

Comment: там внятно написано!

Comment: @lampa любитель разводить холивары?

Comment: @Palmervan признаю, картинка в 2 раза больше грузилась бы в 2 раза быстрее :3 Я вам еще калькулятор могу подарить с округлением :-)

Comment: оба ответа правильные!! и какой мне выбрать правильным?))

Comment: в принципе если добавить в моей функции паттерн начало коней и знак плюся ну и убрать /i то она тоже работает!